# SQL- Iterate through a list of WHERE clause values

Tags: sql

I have a table like so:

```
item_id  order_date    order_qty
1        '1-01-2019'   10
1        '2-05-2019'   20
1        '10-05-2019'  30
2        '5-10-2020'   40
2        '10-02-2018'  10
3        '10-21-2018'  15
4        '10-20-2018'  20
```

I want to find the total order_qty where the item_id matches, and the order_date is between two date values. The issue is that each item_id has different dates to check so they cannot be a constant in the where clause.

Although this will not run I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
Where item_id in (1,2,3) and order_date between (("01-01-2018", "02-02-2018"),
                                                  ("01-02-2019", "03-22-2020"),
                                                  ("11-15-2018", "12-04-2019"))
```

Comment: Hi, please tag a database you use and also add what results you expect to get after the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually want to *iterate*, or just return matching results?

Sounds like this might be the direction you want to go:

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(order_qty)
  FROM Table
 WHERE (item_id = 1 AND order_date BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND '02-02-2018')
    OR (item_id = 2 AND order_date BETWEEN '01-02-2019' AND '03-22-2020')
    OR (item_id = 3 AND order_date BETWEEN '11-15-2018' AND '12-04-2019')
 GROUP BY item_id;
```

(Although comparing string literals to date fields is not a good idea, use `to_date` (Oracle) or equivalent function to translate the string literals to dates. The following is an Oracle example:

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(order_qty)
  FROM Table
 WHERE (item_id = 1 AND order_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-01-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('02-02-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
    OR (item_id = 2 AND order_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-02-2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('03-22-2020', 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
    OR (item_id = 3 AND order_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('11-15-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('12-04-2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY'))
 GROUP BY item_id;
```

Comment: @BrennanCasey I do not understand how this is workng. Can please someone explain it to me ? My answer, among all this three is the only one that has a group by clause and this does not and there for it this will be in error. Or there is some other database I am not aware of where this will work but it say's that it is an Oracle example...

Comment: Good point, I forgot to include a GROUP BY clause, I will fix that. But I think the main hurdle here was understanding how to use OR with multiple conditions grouped together.

Comment: Hi @wweicker nice. Well I am sure(I believe) every help should be appriciated(he is asking a total of... and Iterate through a list of WHERE clause values...) like group by and sum informations... That is why there is accept and vote up. Maybe I am looking at the vote up and accept in a wrong way :)

Answer (score 1):

If the total of each item is what you are looking for with this: "total order_qty..." I believe this is what you need:

```
select item_id
       , sum(order_qty) total
from test
where (item_id = 1 and order_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-06-02')
or (item_id = 2 and order_date BETWEEN '2019-01-02' AND '2018-03-22')
or (item_id = 3 and order_date BETWEEN '2018-11-15' AND '2018-04-12')
group by item_id ;
```

[Here is a demo on SQLServer.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eacd736f376e151b44ddc07dfe51a3e8)

Comment: Hi @BrennanCasey , it would be kind of you if you could give us some feedback ? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `or`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE item_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND
      (order_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-02') OR
       order_date BETWEEN '2019-01-02' AND '2018-03-22') OR
       order_date BETWEEN '2018-11-15' AND '2018-04-12')
      );
```

Note that I also fixed the date constants so they conform to ISO standards.  In some databases, you need to proceed date constants with the `date` keyword.